# ProcessingCompleteFlag SOAP

Tags: node.js, http, soap, https, soap-client

Sometime I get correct response which is expected... But sometimes it fail and return xml like this:

```
 <ProcessingCompleteFlag>false</ProcessingCompleteFlag>
<Transaction
    xmlns:a="http://com.nursys.services.ServiceModel/2012/Transaction"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <a:TransactionID>78803c8a-6195-4d85-90a8-9114408734f9</a:TransactionID>
```

What I should do in that situation? I got TransactionID should I repeat request?

Answer (score 0):

The false response can occur if the Retrieve Nurse Lookup request is made too quickly after the Submit Nurse Lookup request.  Try adding 60 seconds of sleep between the two calls.